# Using Excel 2007, I have 3 outcomes for a cell, the information is also dependant on what goes in two other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

Enlargement:
[image]

We have certain prices for 4 special customers. To help validate the invoicing I am trying to stop human error. If a certain company is placed in column one then it needs to reflect the correct price in cell 5. The price is dependent on how many days the request is for =>3, =2 or =<1. So that is 3 prices, 4 companies and a headache...

eg1 I could not add anymore arguments:

```
=IF(X30="skanska","110",IF(X30="conway","95",IF(X30="cappagh","90",IF(X30="","80","100"))))
```

eg2 again too many arguments:

```
=IF(AC18>=3,IF(X18="skanska","110","70 "),IF(X18="conway","90"," 60"))
```

I am a little lost...

Now I am trying to have a look at `vlookup` and trying to combine with `if` statement.

eg3, I am having problems combining the two:

```
=VLOOKUP(A31,vtable_area,4,0)
```

Comment: Can you [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1010507/edit) to say which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Also it would help to include a screenshot showing where columns X:AC and rows 18:30 are so we can see what you're working with. (But make the data anonymous first)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right lines with a VLOOKUP here. I suggest this approach:
Create a table (on another sheet), with a column for the special customers, and a column for each of the possible number of days (starting from 1, presumably), with the right pricing in them.

Then your VLOOKUP formula could be something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(Customer,VTable,Days+1,FALSE)
```

Where "Customer" is the column of your data with the customer names in (A or wherever it is). So this will find the row with the matching customer name, then return a value from the column matching the number of days. The +1 is to offset to avoid the first column which has the customer names in. In other words, the values for 1 day are in the second column, 2 days in the third, etc.
So yours might look something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(X31,Lookup_table_area,AC31+1,FALSE)
```

You would ideally wrap this in an error catching condition to return values for "standard" customers. Eg:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(X31,Lookup_table_area,AC31+1,FALSE),999)
```

Comment: =VLOOKUP(company_name,vtable_area,_1=<1,_2=2, _3=>3,FALSE)

Comment: Thankyou, I think I need to reference f30 which is where the date numbers are?  This is telling me, to many arguments. Can I show a screenshot somewhere. . .

Comment: @RHart How do you think that formula in your comment will work? VLOOKUP takes exactly 4 arguments. And if you want to add a screenshot, do it in your question, not in my answer.

Comment: I am sorry, just started to use vlookup, so I am still trying to get to grips with how it work. I will have another go with the advice. Thank you.